# Error javascript in TinyMce editor? How about saving data using Name?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, tinymce

I'm using tinyMce editor in my .Net Core project, but the scriptt function of the editor has an id.

```
<script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea#default'
        });
    </script>
```

In javascript I already had an id defined for the textarea

```
        'Desc': $('#p_Ack').val(),//this is how i was adding before the editor was added
        'Desc': $('textarea[name="p_Ack"]').val(),
```

I tried to save by giving a name but still the text in the textarea is blank. What can I do?

```
 <textarea  id="default" name="p_Ack"></textarea>
```

Comment: There has been a strange rapid increase in this account's reputation. I have taken the liberty of notifying the moderators about this, just in case you notice wide fluctuations in your reputation after corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the content in TinyMCE.You can try to use:

```
'Desc':tinymce.get("default").getContent(),
```

or

```
'Desc':tinymce.activeEditor.getContent(),
```